# Android: How to create custom text for website link?

Tags: android

Essentially I want to make something like http://stackoverflow.com appear as "Stack" in a checkedtextview and be a link. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextView can display dumbed-down tagsoup HTML, including `<a href=""/>` tags.  If that's in `strings.xml`, and you set the text using `android:text`, it should just happen automatically.  Otherwise, you'll need to pass the html string to `Html.fromHtml()`.  Example:

```
CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.whatever);
ctv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">Stack</a>"));
```

Your layout should also set `android:linksClickable="true"` on the `CheckedTextView`

Comment: I tried this and it almost works. It just won't let me click the link, even by changing the property in the layout

Comment: The most likely reason for that is `CheckedTextView` is not usually clickable (see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627222/android-checkedtextview-cannot-be-checked/2806669#2806669)) because it's intended as a simplified single-view `ListView` item where the `ListView` handles the checked state via `choiceMode`. You get what what you want with `android:clickable="true"` as well, but if it's in a `ListView`, that could cause problems (such as the click event not triggering the ListView). Also try [CheckBox](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html)