# How to select one checkbox at time in customized listview in android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

after the lot of try , i did not find the solution how to select the one checkbox at a time in customized list view in android. the data come dynamically  through the web service . if i select on one check box in list view and other are uncheck . If any buddy have solution please share with me.[image]

Comment: Why not `RadioButton`? Checkboxes are generally used in places where multiple selections are needed.

Comment: @SakthiKumar k i will change the , how can i do

Comment: you can use radiobutton rather than checkbox..

Comment: @Segi but i want select one at time in list view ,they also select multiple

Answer (score 1):

In click of every check box call notifyDatasetChanged with your adapter and then make it selected .

You can refer to this [Unable to check/uncheck CheckedTextView inside getView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641529/unable-to-check-uncheck-checkedtextview-inside-getview/12642050#12642050) ,this post is little different form what you need but it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Add Below line in your xml file in all radiobutton:

```
<RadioButton 
   ...
   android:onClick="onClickRadioButton"
   ...
/>
```

then put below code in your java file:

```
private RadioButton listRadioButton = null;
   int listIndex = -1;

   public void onClickRadioButton(View v) {
        View vMain = ((View) v.getParent());

        if (listRadioButton != null) listRadioButton.setChecked(false);

        listRadioButton = (RadioButton) v;
           if (listRadioButton.isChecked) {
            listIndex = ((ViewGroup) vMain.getParent()).indexOfChild(vMain); 
        } else {
            listRadioButton = null;
            listIndex = -1
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi,this works when the list fits in 1 page, but when the list is longer than a page, listIndex gets messed up as it starts counting from the first visible list item rather than from the actual start of the list. How can this be fixed?