# difference between checkbox and checkedtextview in Android? Which to use for RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, checkedtextview

I am a beginner in Android Development. When I learned about CheckBox, it's a widget extending compoundbutton and CheckedTextView, widget extending TextView and implements Checkable Interface. When I searched on google, I found no results. Actually, what is the difference between them, If I am using ListView or RecyclerView with CheckBox ability. Which is the better option CheckBox or CheckedTextView?

Answer (score 7):

To supplement the other answers, here is a visual comparison between CheckBox and CheckedTextView. This is running in an emulated Pixel 3 under Android R. Each of these screenshots shows three views inside a vertical LinearLayout.

If you don't specify the checkMark attribute, you get no checkbox on the CheckedTextView:

[image: visual comparison with no checkMark attribute]

with `android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"`:

[image: visual comparison with checkMark=listChoiceIndicatorSingle]

with `android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"`:

[image: visual comparison with checkMark=listChoiceIndicatorMultiple]

There are other differences, but they're covered by other answers.

Answer (score 2):

As recommended from @LarsH I've turned my comment into an answer instead.

The differences is `CheckedTextView` doesn't have a checked/click event, [see here why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2806669/3763032)

Therefore if you want to have checked/click event for free (you can customize the checked/click listener by yourself) choose `CheckBox` and its alignment by default is (left aligned `TextView` & right aligned `CheckBox`)

You might want to align the `TextView`'s text position (optional: if you want to align into different position, e.g: right aligned `TextView` & left aligned `CheckBox`)

Then use it on your `RecyclerView` holder

Answer (score 0):

**CheckBox**: Is a specific type of 2 states button that can be either checked or unchecked.

**CheckedTextView**: Is a TextView with 2 states check and unchecked.

The text is the different between both views, so depend in what you want to do.

About the second question, `RecyclerView` was created as a `ListView` improvement.

Comment: Sorry. I mean CheckBox or CheckedTextView with RecyclerView?

Comment: it is the `TextView` left aligned & `CheckBox` right aligned provided from Google you've got for free @AthiraReddy . Unfortunately `CheckedTextView` doesn't have checked/click event, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2806669/3763032 so, I choose `CheckBox` but customize the TextView align/position (optional) when using `RecyclerView`

Comment: @mochadwi You're the only one who really answered the title question. If you turned your comment into an answer, I think it would be helpful to people who are wondering about this.

Answer (score 0):

so to set item in recyclerview first define the itemLayout as below

```
<CheckBox
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/dialog_checklist_checkbox"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="text"
  android:padding="5dp"
  android:gravity="center"
 />
```

now in recyclerview you can use the checbox properties such as

```
holder.checkBox.setText("position"+position);
```

to set the text of respective checkbox.

you can also use other properties of checkbox such as

```
 holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener();
```

and recyclerview is improved version of listview so try to use recyclerview.

Comment: Sorry, I mean checkBox or checkedtextView?